# log4net not logging precise time to DB

Tags: log4net

I have DB logging setup through log4net. I'm getting same timestamps & no exception object.

**Appender:**

```
<appender name="AsyncDBAppender" type="DA.Systems.Focus.Shared.LogCore.AsynchronousAdoNetAppender, Focus-Shared-LogCore">
    <bufferSize value="1" />
    <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    <connectionString value="data source=dbServer;initial catalog=dbName;persist security info=True;user id=username;password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Connect Timeout=360;App=log4net" />
    <commandText value="INSERT INTO [dbo].[MainLog] ([ProjectId], [ApplicationId], [MachineName],[OperationId], [UserId], [Date],   [Thread] ,[Level],   [Logger], [Message], [Exception])
                                             VALUES (1,           2,               @machineName, @operationId,  @userId,  @logDate, @thread,  @logLevel, @logger,  @message,  @exception)" />
    <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@machineName" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%property{log4net:HostName}" />
        </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@operationId" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%property{OperationId}" />
        </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@userId" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%property{UserId}" />
        </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@logDate" />
        <dbType value="DateTime" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@thread" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="32" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%t" />
        </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@logLevel" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="512" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%p" />
        </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@logger" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="512" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%c" />
        </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@message" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="4000" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%m" />
        </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
        <parameterName value="@exception" />
        <dbType value="String" />
        <size value="4000" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout" />
    </parameter>
</appender>
```

Produces this log:
[image: sample log]

**Issues:**

- Sorting by date destroys the actual sequence. The pattern is a `log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout` & the database column is Datetime2
- When there was an exception, the exception itself didn't get logged

**Exploding code:**

```
try
{
    InfoScope($"{LayerName} -> {callerInfo.MethodName} -> Passes bill created. Notifying Security-System...", userId, operationId);
    var notificationResult = await _securitySystem.FocusBillPaymentNotification(billInfoBdo.BillDetails, userId, operationId);

    if (notificationResult.Result)
    {
        InfoScope($"{LayerName} -> {callerInfo.MethodName} -> Notifying Security-System succeeded: Security-System Receipt #{notificationResult.SecuritySystemReceiptNumber}, Message: {notificationResult.Message}", userId, operationId);
    }
    else
    {
        WarnScope($"{LayerName} -> {callerInfo.MethodName} -> Notifying Security-System failed: {notificationResult.Message}", userId, operationId);
    }
}
catch (Exception exp)
{
    ErrorScope($"{LayerName} -> {callerInfo.MethodName} -> Exception at Security-System Payment notification [{exp.Message}]", exp, userId, operationId);
}
```

How do I make the time stamp more precise?

Why would the exception pobject not get .ToString()/logged?

Here is the Logging Core I use:

```
    #region Error

    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    protected void ErrorScope(string message, string userId, Guid operationId)
    {
        SetUserId(userId);
        SetOperationId(operationId);
        Logger.ErrorFormat(message);
    }

    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    protected void ErrorScope(string message, Exception exception, Guid operationId)
    {
        SetOperationId(operationId);
        Logger.ErrorFormat(message, exception.GetInnerExceptions());
    }

    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    protected void ErrorScope(string message, Exception exception, string userId, Guid operationId)
    {
        SetUserId(userId);
        ErrorScope(message, exception, operationId);
    }

    #endregion
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is not a direct solution to the issue but I did manage to get a proper timestamp in a different manner: I added another column to DB with type as `DateTime2` and default as `SysDateTime()`:

```
RecordStamp DATETIME2 NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_MainLog_RecordStamp DEFAULT (SYSDATETIME())
```

Now, this column is responsible for ensuring each log entry with a valid timestamp.